# Iterate over child nodes on a Telerik MVC TreeView

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I have a Telerik MVC Treeview that i am trying to get the child nodes for using JQuery.  I'm using the "hasChildren" property to tell me if the node has any children and that's working fine.  But I can't seem to figure out the node property that will let me iterate over the child nodes.  "nodes[i].children.view()" gives me an empty array but it should be an array of the child nodes according to this Kendo [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/binding/sort-child-nodes).

```
    var productTreeView = $("#treeviewProducts").data("kendoTreeView");
    var nodes = productTreeView.dataSource.view();  
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
         if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
            var childrenNodes = nodes[i].children.view();
            for (var x = 0; x < childrenNodes.length; x++) {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:  The code above works fine if the node with children is expanded but does not work when the node with children is collapsed because LazyLoading for child nodes was enabled (thanks DontVoteMeDown).  Either turn that off or expand all nodes before running the code (productTreeView.expand(".k-item");).

Comment: It is set as lazy loading for child nodes?

Comment: Yes that would be what the problem is.

Comment: I'm gonna tell what I did some years ago to get rid of the same problem of yours. I'm not sure if was or there is a better solution though, native or not. But what I did was something like a recursive algorithm through the nodes, which uses [`expand()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/methods/expand) to make the request to the server to fill its children. But I couldn't get it's response because there is no such event in the widget, so I have bound an [Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to get the DOM changes in that node..

Comment: ...that observer calls the next iteration of that recursive algorithm on all new children once the request is complete and the nodes are create, and it goes on. It is a hell of a work to make it happen, but it works until this day and I'm not touching it too soon, unless they release a decent native feature for that purpose.